With lsp-mode, why do I get an unknown notification about refreshed rules from semgrep?
I constantly get this message:
⛔ Warning (lsp-mode): Unknown notification: semgrep/rulesRefreshed

This is something new. Can I somehow pin the commit, so that I can got back to where it didn't show, maybe?

It's not a very good idea to set the warning-minimum-level to :error because of losing important feed-backs.
This code works but skip ALL lsp-mode warning :
(add-to-list 'warning-suppress-log-types '(lsp-mode))
(add-to-list 'warning-suppress-types '(lsp-mode))

So I create an advise to filter the Emacs warning by string regexp

I cannot answer what causes the issue - but setting the warning level to :error can avoid this pop-up.
This is a thread that talks about it

Warnings buffer popping up frequently for some LSP servers is annoying.
It can be suppressed by setting customization variable warning-minimum-level to :error.
M-x customize-variable warning-minimum-level

if you are on doom-emacs, add it in your config.el -
(after! lsp-mode
  (defun ak-lsp-ignore-semgrep-rulesRefreshed (workspace notification)
    "Ignore semgrep/rulesRefreshed notification."
    (when (equal (gethash "method" notification) "semgrep/rulesRefreshed")
      (lsp--info "Ignored semgrep/rulesRefreshed notification")
      t)) ;; Return t to indicate the notification is handled

  (advice-add 'lsp--on-notification :before-until #'ak-lsp-ignore-semgrep-rulesRefreshed))


for vanila emacs, you may have this in your configuration file...
(with-eval-after-load 'lsp-mode
  (defun ak-lsp-ignore-semgrep-rulesRefreshed (workspace notification)
    "Ignore semgrep/rulesRefreshed notification."
    (when (equal (gethash "method" notification) "semgrep/rulesRefreshed")
      (lsp--info "Ignored semgrep/rulesRefreshed notification")
      t)) ;; Return t to indicate the notification is handled

  (advice-add 'lsp--on-notification :before-until #'ak-lsp-ignore-semgrep-rulesRefreshed))

